# Not able to display Chinese characters after loading it to Postgres DB

Tags: mysql, postgresql, encoding

I have a source file which contains Chinese characters. After loading that file into a table in Postgres DB, all the characters are garbled and I'm not able to see the Chinese characters. The encoding on Postgres DB is UTF-8. I'm using the psql utility on my local mac osx to check the output. The source file was generated from mySql db using mysqldump and contains only insert statements.

```
INSERT INTO "trg_tbl" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col7", 
                       "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", "col14", 
                       "col15", "col16", "col17", "col18", "col19", "col20", "col21", 
                       "col22", "col23", "col24", "col25", "col26", "col27", "col28", 
                       "col29", "col30", "col31", "col32", "col33") 
VALUES ( 1, 1, 'ä¸Žé<U+009D>žç½‘_é¦–é¡µ&é¢‘é<U+0081>“é¡µé¡¶éƒ¨å¹¿å‘Šä½<U+008D>ï¼ˆ946Ã—90ï¼‰',
               'é€šæ <U+008F>å¹¿å‘Šï¼ˆLeaderboard Bannerï¼‰',
         0,3,'',946,90,'','','','',0,'f',0,'',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
         '2011-08-19 07:29:56',0,0,0,'',NULL,0,NULL,'CPM',NULL,NULL,0);
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: The mysql database was also encoded with UTF-8? The file you save was also encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, both are showing UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

The text was mangled before producing that SQL statement.  You probably wanted the text to start with `与` instead of the "Mojibake" version: `ä¸Ž`.  I suggest you fix the dump either to produce utf8 characters or hex.  Then the load *may* work, or there may be more places to specify utf8, such as `SET NAMES` or the equivalent.

Also, for Chinese, `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is preferred in MySQL.

`é<U+009D>ž` is so mangled I don't want to figure out the second character.